# Calling browser with ABAP in Cloud system possible?

Tags: abap

Any chance to call a browser window from ABAP in an ABAP Cloud system, e.g. like it is possible with cl_abap_browser in OP systems, e.g. to display a string or suchlike (other than the console display option via if_oo_adt_classrun)?

Comment: What's your usecase? "to display a string" is quite generic

Answer (score 2):

The class [`cl_abap_browser`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenhtml_browser_abexa.htm) is used to open a browser inside of a *SAP GUI Dynpro Session*. In the [BTP ABAP Environment](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/04/sap-cloud-platform-abap-environment/) or [S/4 HANA Cloud System](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/09/30/steampunk-is-going-all-in/) there is no SAP GUI access.

If you'd expose the data as an OData Service then you can easily show it in a browser as the client *is itself* a webbrowser.

Comment: The fact that there is no SAP GUI access is understood. That's what I meant by "cl_abap_browser in OP systems". Actually, the use case is to output not only strings but also internal tables and structures (with asJson or asXML). I simply want to output stuff in a browser that I could output with if_oo_adt_classrun in the console. Imagine a simple calculator (without input parameters -> That would be another question, how to provide input parameters) which is implemented in a class (certainly not a report). Then, execute the class and display the result of the calculation in a browser window.

Comment: cl_demo_output is well known, too. Awesome means for my purpose - in OP! This class is not available in the cloud. As mentioned, reports and this class are no option. Currently only the said out method of  if_oo_adt_classrun~main.

Comment: Oh, true. I thought that class was released ...